# Using len() and def __len__(self): to build a class

Tags: python, class, optimization, coding-style

Just curious,

Is there any difference (advantages and disadvantages) between using `len()` or `def __len__()` when I build a class? And which is the best Python style?

```
   class foo(object):
      def __init__(self,obs=[])
         self.data = obs
         self.max = max(obs)
         self.min = min(obs)
         self.len = len(obs)
```

or

```
   class foo(object):
      def __init__(self,obs=[])
         self.data = obs
         self.max = max(obs)
         self.min = min(obs)
      def __len__(self):
         return len(self.data)
```

Comment: How would the first one be equivalent to the second one?

Comment: Note that you should not use `[]` as a default value of a keyword parameter unless you know what you are doing. See ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941)

Comment: In the first example, `self.len = len(obs)` assigns a data member `self.len` to the *initial* length of obs. `self.len` is not a function. If obs changes after initialization, `self.len` won't reflect that.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There is a *huge* difference.

The `__len__()` method is a hook method. The `len()` *function* will use the `__len__` method if present to query your object for it's length.

The *normal* API people expect to use is the `len()` method, using a `.len` attribute instead would deviate from that norm.

If the length of `self.data` is not expected to change, you can always cache the length in an attribute and have `.__len__()` return that attribute.

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, obs=None):
        if obs is None:  # provide a default if no list was passed in.
            obs = []
        self.data = obs
        self.max = max(obs)
        self.min = min(obs)
        self._data_len = len(obs)

    def __len__(self):
        return self._data_len
```

Answer (score 10):

There are several differences:

1. Only the second approach will give you the familiar `len(obj)` syntax for `foo`. The first will require `obj.len()`.
2. If the length of `self.data` can change post-construction, only the second version will reflect the new length.