# tqdm progressbar and zip built-in do not work together

Tags: python, console, progress-bar, tqdm

tqdm is a Python module to easily print in the console a dynamically updating progressbar.  For example

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep
for _ in tqdm(range(10)): 
    sleep(0.1)
```

prints a dynamic progressbar in the console for 1sec as the iteration executes:
[image]

I have not figured out how to use tqdm with the builtin zip object.
The use case of this would be to iterate over two corresponding lists with a console progressbar.
For example, I would expect this to work:

```
for _, _ in tqdm(zip(range(10), range(10))):
    sleep(0.1)
```

but the progressbar printed to the console in this case is not correct:
[image]

A workaround is to use tqdm with enumerate, however then an iterator index must be defined and managed.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`tqdm` can be used with `zip` if a `total` keyword argument is provided in the `tqdm` call.

The following example demonstrates iteration over corresponding elements in two lists with a working `__tqdm__` progress bar for the case where a `total` keyword argument is used:
[image]

The issue is that `tqdm` needs to know the length of the iterable ahead of time.  Because `zip` is meant to handle iterables with different lengths, it does not have as an attribute a single length of its arguments.

So, `__tqdm__` still works nicely with `zip`, you just need to provide a little manual control with the `total` keyword argument.

Comment: To further automate this, you can go ahead and have a list like `list = [numbers, letters]` and get the largest list by `longest = list[sorted([(i,len(l)) for i,l in enumerate(list)], key=lambda t: t[1])[-1][0]]` then simply put `total=len(longest)`. This approach will also work for `itertools.zip_longest`.

Answer (score 27):

Using `tqdm>=4.42.0`, you should do:

```
from tqdm.contrib import tzip
from time import sleep

for _, _ in tzip(range(10), range(10)):
    sleep(0.1)
```

Just to note  in https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#faq-and-known-issues:

> - Wrapping generators:
>
>   - Generator wrapper functions tend to hide the length of iterables. `tqdm` does not.
>   - Replace `tqdm(enumerate(...))` with `enumerate(tqdm(...))` or `tqdm(enumerate(x), total=len(x), ...)`. The same applies to `numpy.ndenumerate`.
>   - Replace `tqdm(zip(a, b))` with `zip(tqdm(a), b)` or even `zip(tqdm(a), tqdm(b))`.
>   - The same applies to `itertools`.
>   - Some useful convenience functions can be found under `tqdm.contrib`.

Answer (score 5):

For you have a progress-bar is expected that you can predict the length of your data structure.

`range` implements the [hook method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15114062/2241168) `__len__`, so you can discover the length doing built-in `len`

```
>>> dir(range(10))
[ '__le__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'count', 'index', 'start', 'step', 'stop']

>>> len(range(10))
10
```

`zip`, however, does not provide a way to guess the length of the wrapped structure, so probably that's why because `tqdm` can not show the progress bar.

```
dir(zip(range(10))) # no __len__ here
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__next__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']

>>> len(zip(range(10)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len()
```

**Edit:**

Yeah, that's it. Look the [docs](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/master/README.rst)

> ...
>
> Wrapping enumerated iterables: use `enumerate(tqdm(...))` instead of
>   `tqdm(enumerate(...))`. The same applies to `numpy.ndenumerate`. This is
>   because `enumerate` functions tend to hide the length of iterables. `tqdm`
>   does not.
>
> ...
>
> Manual control on `tqdm()` updates by using a `with` statement:
>
> ```
> with tqdm(total=100) as pbar:
>     for i in range(10):
>         pbar.update(10)
> ```
>
> **If the optional variable total (or an iterable with `len()`) is
>   provided, predictive stats are displayed.**
>
> `with` is also optional (you can just assign `tqdm()` to a variable, but
>   in this case don't forget to `del` or `close()` at the end:
>
> ```
> pbar = tqdm(total=100)
> for i in range(10):
>     pbar.update(10)
> pbar.close()
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this post.  It helped figure out a way to initialize tqdm with the 'total' keyword argument that makes it work with zip.

Answer (score -1):

```
from tqdm import tqdm

a = range(10)
b = range(10)

for _ in zip(tqdm(a), b):
    pass
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. This is particularly important when answering old questions with existing answers (this question is nearly six years old). Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked, and how it improves upon what is already here. See [answer].